# Show Label field for each sub-task in the task

Tags: jira

When Task (issue) is opened the list of sub-tasks is displayed (below the Attachments).

When we create a sub-task we assign a label to it. So when the list of sub-tasks is shown we want them to be shown with their labels. But labels are not shown now.

Is it possible to make Jira show labels in the list of sub-tasks?

I'm not the Jira administrator.